# Location of "SQL Server Database Project" template in VS2015?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, one of the New Project templates is "SQL Server | SQL Server Database Project".  The "SQL Server" category does not appear on my filesystem in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates` location, so where is Visual Studio getting that project template from?

Comment: "Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0" is not the correct folder for VS2015.

Comment: [Version 9.0 is Visual Studio 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History). Have you looked in `Program Files` rather than `Program Files (x86)`? Visual Studio 2015 is v14.0.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found it in the end by searching for the `.sqlproj` file.  It's still not in the default place [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx) claims project templates should be, but the template seems to be at:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\ProjectItems`

Comment: Care to link to the MSDN page which claims these templates should be elsewhere?

Comment: Templates provided by extensions (And the SQL Tools install as a Visual Studio extension) go in the individual extension's folders. I guess that the author of that particular page didn't have extensions in mind when writing it.